# Is Karma discussed in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, karma, reference-request

In the Vedas is Karma talked of or discussed? And if it is discussed please put the verses.

Comment: Your question could be a duplicate of 
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/origin-of-the-law-of-karma 
There are abundant of references on this topic in  Jnaana Kanda of Vedas

Answer (score 1):

Karma is the reason for embodiment.., for a Jiva to acquire forms in various places till it attains the highest destiny . (Shvetashvatara Upanishad 5.11 Translation Swami Tyagisananda RK mutt)
[image]